# RSA - plaintext equal ciphertext

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, prime-numbers, decryption

Just started learning about RSA cryptography so forgive me if I made any mistakes or misunderstandings.

```
n = 1024-bit integer (product of two large primes p*q)
e = 65537 (standard exponent)
```

However I also have some ciphertext all encrypted with the same keys.

> c<sub>1</sub> = m<sub>1</sub><sup>e</sup> MOD n
>  c<sub>2</sub> =
> m<sub>2</sub><sup>e</sup> MOD n
>  ...
>  c<sub>k</sub> =
> m<sub>k</sub><sup>e</sup> MOD n

Among these there is a particular ciphertext.

> c = m<sup>e</sup> MOD n
> m == c
> m == m<sup>e<sup>k</sup></sup> MOD n
> So **e<sup>k</sup> - 1** is a multiple of **ϕ(n)**?

If not mistaken, therefore, it is possible to derive the following equations.

> m<sup>e</sup> ≡ m MOD n
>  m<sup>e</sup> - m ≡ 0 MOD n
> m<sup>e - 1</sup> ≡ 0 MOD n
>  m<sup>e - 1</sup> ≡ 0 MOD (p*q)
> m<sup>e - 1</sup> ≡ 0 MOD p AND m<sup>e - 1</sup> ≡ 0 MOD q

Knowing all these strange characteristics, is there any way to obtain the private key and consequently be able to decrypt the other ciphertexts?

Comment: Critic 1: From $m≡m^{(e^k)}\pmod n$ it can't be concluded that $e^k-1$ is a multiple of $ϕ(n)$; the implication is in the other direction. Critic 2: You can go from $m^e-m\equiv0\pmod n$ to $m(m^{e-1}-1)≡0\pmod n$, but from there you can't quite conclude that $m^{e-1}≡1\pmod n$, much less that $m^{e-1}≡0\pmod n$ as in the question. Hint: but from $m(m^{e-1}-1)≡0\pmod n$ you can go to $m(m^{e-1}-1)≡0\pmod p$ and $m(m^{e-1}-1)≡0\pmod q$, and then it's at least possible that one the two equations holds because $m≡0\pmod p$ or $m≡0\pmod q$. Assuming that, it's easy to factor $n$. Else, well…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to obtain the private key and consequently be able to decrypt the other ciphertexts?

Sometimes.  A fuller answer involves number theory (but to understand why RSA works, you really need to know the basics anyways).

First off, a definition: the *order* of a value $a$ (modulo $p$) is the smallest positive integer $x$ such that $a^x \equiv 1 \pmod p$.  The value $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$ doesn't have an order (it's not considered an element in the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$); all other values have an order (assuming $p$ is prime).

Now, if we have $m^e = m \pmod {pq}$ (where $pq=n$, expressed as its prime factors), then we know that:

- Either $m = 0 \pmod p$, or the order of $m$ modulo $p$ is a divisor of $e-1$
- Either $m = 0 \pmod q$, or the order of $m$ modulo $q$ is a divisor of $e-1$

Now, if either $m = 0 \pmod p$ or $m = 0 \pmod q$, then a simple computation $\gcd(m, n)$ reveals the factorization (unless both are true, in which case we have $m = 0$; we can't deduce anything from that).

The other case is if both have orders; if the two orders are different, say, $x$ and $y$ (with $x < y$), then a simple computation of $\gcd( m^x - 1, n )$ reveals the factorization.

On the other, if the two orders are the same, well, the knowledge of $m$ doesn't reveal a factorization.

And, because $e$ is typically small, $e-1$ is easy to factor, hence it is practical to test $\gcd( m^x - 1, n )$ for all divisors $x$ of $e-1$

Now, there are some simplifications: to test if $m$ is order 1 (either modulo $p$ or $q$), we can just compute $\gcd( m - 1, n )$ (and if both sides have that order, that corresponds to $m = 1$)

And, for the order $2$, it turns out we can compute $\gcd( m + 1, n )$ (and if both sides have that order, that corresponds to $m = n-1$)

In most cases, computing $\gcd(m, n), \gcd(m-1, n), \gcd(m+1, n)$ is sufficient to recover the factorization; however the fuller test will catch some more cases.